# I/o disk error when resume from hibernate/suspend on battery power Notebook

Tags: disk

The problem is appearing only on battery power when I resume laptop from hibernate/suspend.
Ubuntu starts normally, I can login, Unity starts and... sometimes in different time orders system freeze. I can't do anything. When I push ctrl+alt+f2 insted of console with login prompt i get message for example i/o disk error read from 12347586.
It looks like hard disk hardware problem (bad sectors) but i check and disk is good.
On power pack i don't have that issue.
That is my first serious contact with ubuntu.
Earlier I had ubuntu 11.10 for few days. From what I remember I don't have that problems with 11.10.
I installed ubuntu 12.04 manually. Swap size is right. 
It's look like power menagment problems with disk acces on battery power.

System Ubuntu 12.04
Latitude XT
c2d ulv 1.33
3gb ram
disk zif pata 120gb
ati x1250

Whether somebody can help me?
I am greeting
Mikolaj

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu have problems with  n-trig driver display maybe this cause the problem...disable it and try again...
is this the only one issue?  what about the graphic display issue?  ati x1250 shows strange lines on the top panel

google translate :P

Comment: This is a disk error, not a graphics card failure.